# Conditioned probability with Bayes' theorem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

> 20% of people with a gene called G develops a disease called E, 10% of people have the G gene, and 5% of people develop E. If an individual develops E, what is the probability of who has the G gene?

My attempt

$P(E|G)=\frac{1}{5}$,  $P(G)=\frac{1}{10}$, $P(E)=\frac{1}{20}$

Using Bayes' theorem
$P(G|E)=\frac{P(E|G) P(G)}{P(E)}=\frac{2}{5}$

Is my reasoning correct? If not, could you help me? Thank you

Comment: Your reasoning of using Bayes' theorem is correct but your numbers are not. 20% is $\frac{1}{5}$ and 5% is $\frac{1}{20}$

Comment: Yes, thank you very much, I just noticed that mistake.